# Resuming AVPlayer after being interrupted with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, swiftui

I'm building a radio streaming app using `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem`. I've built my app to keep playing the radio in the background like this:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

After the `AVPlayer` is interrupted (for example, when the user receives a call) the `AVPlayer` isn't resuming playing. I need to actively play it again in order to listen to the streaming.

How can I make the `AVPlayer` to automatically resume after being interrupted using `SwiftUI`? (I've found some solutions but non of them is suitable for working with `SwiftUI`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing related to SwiftUI, or UI in general, to restart playback after an interruption.

As said in apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html):

First register to the notification of the interruption:

```swift
func registerForNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                                           name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption,
                                           object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
}
```

Then handle the notification like this:

```swift
func handleInterruption(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let info = notification.userInfo,
        let typeValue = info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
            return
    }
    if type == .began {
        // Interruption began, take appropriate actions (save state, update user interface)
    }
    else if type == .ended {
        guard let optionsValue =
            userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else {
                return
        }
        let options = AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
        if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
            // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, you could explain better the issue you are having with other solutions that don't work in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I know, `NotificationCenter` shouldn't be used when developing with `SwiftUI` or other `MVVM`. Isn't it right?

Comment: I don't think that's right. SwiftUI is just a framework for building UI in a declarative way. It has nothing to do with the business logic (like playing or pausing audio). NotificationCenter is also compatible with the new combine framework (you can extract a publisher form it), so there's really no reason not to use it, especially for system notifications. Also, I don't think there is another way to respond to interruptions.

Comment: Extra: might be helpful https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-be-notified-when-your-swiftui-app-moves-to-the-background
you can listen when the app goes background or enters foreground

Answer (score 4):

**SwiftUI**

Call the .onReceive function on your play button like this:

```swift
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification)) { event in
    guard let info = event.userInfo,
        let typeValue = info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
            return
    }
    if type == .began {
        // Interruption began, take appropriate actions (save state, update user interface)
    }
    else if type == .ended {
        guard let optionsValue =
            info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else {
                return
        }
        let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
        if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
            // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```